# how to create a dictionary from a dataframe where the keys are column names and values are the number of values under each column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, dataset

I have a data frame whose dimensions are (356027, 163).
I want to create a dictionary from the data frame where i will have 163 keys with values which are the number of entries in them(i.e. number of non null entries)
I tried using the to_dict() operation but couldn't insert the values as the count of entries under each column

```
dict1 = data-frame.to_dict('index')
print(dict1)
for i in dict1:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) with [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html), loop by dict is not necessary:

```
out = data-frame.count().to_dict()
```